# Android GeoCoder location search produce wrong location

Tags: android, search, maps

I am trying to add twitter style add location to feed.
When I try to search cities for instance words starts with "new york" results comes with many different results with new york as image

[image]

My geocode is as below

```
public static List<String> getAddressesFromLocation(Context context, double lat, double lon) {

    Locale current = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(context, current);
    List<Address> addresses;
    int maxResult = 5;
    List<String> addressList = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        // May throw an IOException
        addresses = coder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, maxResult);
        if (addresses == null) {
            return null;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < addresses.size(); j++) {
            Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(j);

            String city = (returnedAddress.getLocality() == null || returnedAddress.getLocality().isEmpty()) ? "" : (returnedAddress.getLocality() + ", ");
            String state = (returnedAddress.getAdminArea() == null || returnedAddress.getAdminArea().isEmpty()) ? "" : (returnedAddress.getAdminArea() + ", ");

            String country = (returnedAddress.getCountryName() == null || returnedAddress.getCountryName().isEmpty()) ? "" : returnedAddress.getCountryName();

            if((city == null || city.isEmpty()) && (state == null || state.isEmpty())){
                continue;
            }
            if(city.equals(state)){
                state = "";
            }
            addressList.add(city + state + country);
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return addressList;
}
```

Everything works fine but with wrong results. What is the problem?